# Any way to get high quality live proxies other than buying them from a website?

Tags: tls, proxy, socks5

Free & public proxies are not safe when transmitting sensitive info,  but even if they were are much too slow. I can't purchase due a potential security risk. I looked into and tried proxy scraping, but that's just gathering a large amount of public free proxies.

I'm curious if there is a method, tool, or any way to create or find fast secure proxies of all kinds at their source? Like however the sites that sell them get them. The tool or method doesn't need to be free.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The sites that sell proxies either have setup these proxies themselves or just scan the internet and look for open proxies. As you discovered yourself, these free proxies are usually not safe. They might sniff the traffic, inject advertisements or even malware - because this is their business model.

The only way to get a proxy you could consider as secure is to either create such a proxy yourself or to somebody you trust with creating such a proxy. This rules out any companies or tools which just find such proxies, because there is no way to find out if the proxy is really secure, i.e. not modifying the traffic and not even sniffing to the traffic, not keeping log files etc.